# All requests return one by one, not concurrently

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await

could you please help me with my code. I need run requests concurrently but get requests one by one. Below code example (use VueJS method/function)

```
async manageData() {
   // array of chart's properties
   const charts = await axios.post('/report/chart_data', {id: this.id);
   // concurrent requests with variable 'charts'
   const result = await Promise.all(
      charts.map((chart, key) => axios.post('/report/data_range', {id: key}))
   );
}
```

[image]

Comment: What makes you feel that the requests are happening serially?  And just to confirm, which requests do you feel are happening serially?

Comment: The timeline suggests that there may be something on the backend preventing the requests from being processed concurrently.  You'll need to share more details on how the backend is implemented in order for us to help.

Comment: This request "await Promise.all(....)" goes serially. I see that in network info (see the attached screenshot)

Comment: Does the screenshot means that requests run concurrently at one time but backend return results with delay?

Comment: The timeline suggests that the browser is starting all of the requests pretty much simultaneously, but that the backend is delaying the sending responses in a step-ladder fashion.  This could happen if the requests, for example, access the database in a way that requires the accessed rows to be locked.  Or if the backend is implemented in a way such that each request prevents other requests from being processed.  Either way, the problem seems to be on the backend.

Comment: Thank! I'm glad that async works properly! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   const charts = await axios.post('/report/chart_data', {id: this.id);
```

Will make a single request and wait until it is completed before continuing. This is necessary, as you then use the `charts` response to form your subsequent requests.

```
      charts.map((chart, key) => axios.post('/report/data_range', {id: key}))
```

Will make `charts.length` number of requests in parallel. This is desirable per your description and because it appears the requests are independent.

Your screenshot supports this analysis (first request is waiting for a response before subsequent requests are made in parallel).

If you know the length of the `charts` response, you could parallelize the first and subsequent requests, since you only use `key` (index) and not the actual `chart`s to perform the latter requests.

If your concerned with why your latter requests seem to take steadily increasing time to respond, that may be just a coincidence in complexity of each request, or, as user ctt@ pointed out in the comments, could indicate your backend is not handling the requests simultaneously. But that doesn't seem to be your concern (per your comment).